# Create a custom view to display data as in http://www.buzzapp.de/ app in xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am new to xamarin and I am trying to create the interface of http://www.buzzapp.de/ mobile app. I think to extend VIEW. But I am completely stocked to extend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create cross-platform app, start from looking at [Xamarin Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms).
By the way you 3 options to create custom view:

1. Extend `View` class and implement your UI using either [XAML](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/) or coded UI.
2. Extend `View` (or one of its child) and create a number of [custom renderers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) by the number of platforms you'd like to support.
3. Create completely custom native controls and use them directly from `Activity` and `AppDelegate`.

Option 2 is the most attractive if you need to create very custom UI or just use all the features of native controls. In this case you will also able to use Forms features on your controls (data binding for example) to connect newly created cross-platform control with your existing app UI.

Be more concrete posting your question according to the [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I want a 3d view but do not know how to do that ?

Comment: Start from figuring out how to implement it natively. Then read about how to bring this to cross-clatform.